# How to extract words from a list of list that begin with x

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, nested-lists

I want to extract all words that begins with each alphabet from a list of list.
I have following code but it does not work for a list of list.

```
my_list= [['ARON', '0.1'], ['BEY', '0.2'], ['ABI', '0.05'], ['ZBBY', '0.9'], ['KB', '0.4']]


result = []

for i in sorted_firstnames:
    if i[0] == 'a'.upper():
          result.append(i)

result
```

Comment: please provide the desired output for the sample input. Thanks

Comment: `if i[0][0].upper() == 'A'`. Got your `str.upper():` the wrong way round and missing an additional index

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
>>> x = 'a'
>>> print([i for i in my_list if i[0][0].casefold() == x])
[['ARON', '0.1'], ['ABI', '0.05']]
```

and if you want only word,

```
>>> print([i[0] for i in my_list if i[0][0].casefold() == x])
['ARON', 'ABI']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your code something like following to fetch just the names which starts with 'A' :

```
my_list= [['ARON', '0.1'], ['BEY', '0.2'], ['ABI', '0.05'], ['ZBBY', '0.9'], ['KB', '0.4']]

result = []

for i in my_list: 
    if i[0][0] == 'a'.upper():
          result.append(i[0]) 

print(result)
```

Result is :

```
['ARON', 'ABI']
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my take.

```
my_list= [['ARON', '0.1'], ['BEY', '0.2'], ['ABI', '0.05'], ['ZBBY', '0.9'], ['KB', '0.4']]

alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvtwxyz'

result = {k:[sublist[0] for sublist in my_list if sublist[0][0].lower() == k] for k in alphabet}
print(result)  # prints: {'v': [], 'c': [], 'b': ['BEY'], 'o': [], ...}
active = {k:v for k,v in result.items() if v}
print(active)  # prints:  {'z': ['ZBBY'], 'b': ['BEY'], 'a': ['ARON', 'ABI'], 'k': ['KB']}
```

Scans every letter and puts the results in `result`. it then isolates the letters that actually returned a match in `active`.

You can combine the two dictionary comprehensions in one but the result would not be very readable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `startswith` function to check the starting letter of the String.

Please try this code :

```
my_list= [['ARON', '0.1'], ['BEY', '0.2'], ['ABI', '0.05'], ['ZBBY', '0.9'], ['KB', '0.4']]
result = []

for i in my_list:
    if i[0].startswith('a'.upper()):
          result.append(i[0])

print result
```

**Output:**

```
['ARON', 'ABI']
```

Please let me know in terms of any queries.